# Would you say "He's someone you'd rather not meet here"?

Tags: relative-clauses, who-whom

Is this sentence grammatically acceptable?

> He is someone you would rather not meet here.

Or does it need to be something like this?

> He is someone **who/whom** you would rather not **to** meet here.

Comment: I don't think *not to meet* should be there. Just *not meet* would be fine with _whom_. **He is someone whom you would rather not meet here.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sentence is perfectly correct, idiomatic English. I'd just stick with that if I were you.

As for the variations in your second sentence... "Not to meet" is completely incorrect. Don't use that. You *could* use *who* there, but it isn't necessary and I think the sentence reads much better without it. So I'd just go with your first instinct and use the original sentence!

Comment: Thank you. Would you please point out the reason "not to meet" is incorrect? I'm just confused because there are many sentences in dictionaries that match that pattern. For instance, in Longman you would find this sentence: "You were wrong not **to** inform the police."

Comment: @Nate That's correct—you could also say "You were wrong not to meet with the police" and that would be correct too. *Not to meet* just isn't correct in this particular sentence. *To meet* is the infinitive form, and *meet* is not. Hmm. I'm not 100% sure how to explain *why*. Consider these sentences: "I would not like to meet with you." & "I will meet with you." In the first, "like" is the conjugated verb, and "to meet" describes the thing you wouldn't like. In the second, the verb is the conjugated "meet". ...I'm not sure that made any sense. If it's still unclear let me know, I'll try again.

Comment: Your examples made it much clearer. Now I'm just wondering could we also say "I would not like/enjoy meeting you"?

Comment: @Nate That might make sense in specific contexts, like “If you had a violent handshake, I would not like meeting you.” because you're specifically nominating the action of meeting someone in a more continuous sense. Generally, you'll want to refer to meeting someone as an instant in time, which means using the infinitive (“to meet”). _Note: it has become idiomatically acceptable (in the US at least) to say “(it was) nice meeting you!”, but it is better grammar (or: the minimum of UK propriety) to say “(it was) nice to have met you.”_

Comment: @WendiKidd Actually, *meet* isn't finite either in this context.  The finite form that agrees with *he* is *meets*, but if we replace the subject *you* with *he*, the verb form doesn't change to *meets*.  That is to say, we can see that it doesn't inflect, so we can tell that it's not finite.  Therefore we can see that in this context *meet* is in fact a bare infinitive following the modal auxiliary *would* (with *rather not* intervening).  The question is not one of finiteness, but whether or not the particle *to* should mark the infinitive.

Comment: @Nate Yeah, listen to snailboat on this one. She's got a far better grasp of the reasons *why* than I do, here.